# Is there a hot-key for new identity?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle

In the Tor Browser, you can get a new identity by clicking a button with your mouse. Is there a keyboard hot-key or combination for that?

Answer (score 3):

They work on this: [#17599: Please add keyboard shortcuts for New Identity and New Tor Circuit for this Site](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/ticket/17599)

Follow this ticket to get know when it's ready.

Information in the ticket tells it will be something like:
New Identity: <kbd>Ctrl/Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd>
New Tor Circuit for this Site: <kbd>Ctrl/Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>

But for now my friend there is no working keyboard short-cut.

Answer (score 0):

The *New Identity* / *New Tor Circuit for this Site* shortcuts were [added](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/ticket/17599) in Tor Browser 6.0. The shortcuts are the same as the proposed ones mentioned in [krang](https://tor.stackexchange.com/a/9623/401)'s answer:

> New Identity: <kbd>Ctrl/Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd>
>   New Tor Circuit for this Site: <kbd>Ctrl/Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>